# android.widget.FrameLayout cannot be cast to androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar Error

Tags: java, android, androidx, android-framelayout

I am trying to implement searchview on my activity. But whenever I am using framelayout to contain toolbar and searchview, I am getting error of "android.widget.FrameLayout cannot be cast to androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar"

```html
  <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

   <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/search_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    <com.miguelcatalan.materialsearchview.MaterialSearchView
    android:id="@+id/search_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </FrameLayout>
```

My activity OnCreate method, I'm using

```html
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar);
searchView = (MaterialSearchView) findViewById(R.id.search_view);
```

Is there any alternative to Framelayout ? or what could be possible solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Upload your fragment or activity class as well?

Comment: I have used androidx appcompat for my activity and have declaered Toolbar and searchview as given above.

Comment: I don't see any view whose id is `main_toolbar`